# How to get all related information with a single SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I have three objects: `Master`, `Join`, and `Item`. `Join` has a Master-Detail relationship to `Master` called `Master__c` and a lookup relationship to `Item` called `Item__c`.

```
Join
  ├───.Master__c     // <-- master-detail
  |      └───Master
  |       
  ├───.Item__c
  |      |
         └───Item  // <-- Lookup
```

Given a list of `Master` `Ids`, I want all of the `Master` records along with the names of the related `Item` records through `Join`. How do I do this?

Comment: Does the graph represent the relations correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the objects and relationships you described correctly,

Master is the parent object and can have zero or more Join records.
Join is a child of Master and can have zero or 1 reference to an Item.

```
Master
  └──Join
       └──Item
```

If so, you can use a SOQL query like this:

```
SELECT id, name, 
                (SELECT name, item__r.name FROM Master__r) 
FROM Master 
WHERE id in (<list of master ids>)
```